# uninitialized constant Name_of_controller::Savon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, savon

I am using savon gem to interact with a SOAP API.

```
    client = Savon.client(wsdl: "http://karvymfs.com/CP_STP_SERVICE/STPService.svc?singleWsdl")
    xmlkarvy = "<file>...........</file>"
    @response = client.call(:stp_upload, message: {"FundCode" =>"AXF","UserID" => ".............", "Password"=> "..................", "ARNCode" => "..........", "IPAddress" => "..............", "XMLFile" => xmlkarvy , "Branch" => "?"})
```

Works absolutely fine in IRB but when the same code is used in a controller I get the error.
uninitialized constant ControllerName::Savon

Answer (score 0):

write following before controller class

```
require 'savon'
```

This is mentioned in the gem documentation too.

Comment: cannot load such file -- savon

Comment: i hope you have already added `gem 'savon', '~> 2.3.0'` in your gemfile and have run `bundle install` .

Comment: yes I have added the gem in the gemfile and run bundle install.